# SoundCloud API can return unescaped <script> blocks from tracks' titles

Tags: soundcloud

While trying out the SoundCloud API, I discovered that when querying `/tracks`, the API can return tracks with title fields which have unescaped script tags in them.

Here's an example:

```
SC.initialize({

    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'

});

SC.get('/tracks', {

    q: '', limit: 200, tags: "ning", linked_partitioning: 1


}).then(function(tracks) {

for (var i = 0;i < tracks.collection.length;i++){               

    document.write(tracks.collection[i].title + "<br />");

}

}).catch(function(error) {

    console.log(error);     

});
```

This returns a list of tracks including this one: `https://soundcloud.com/laguhitss/merem-melek-desy-ning-nong` (be careful, it sounds horrible).  You'll notice the title is `Merem Melek Desy Ning Nong Mp3<script>window.location='http://mymp3.asia/'</script>`

When this title is injected unescaped in to a page (as above, or with `.innerHTML =`, etc), it will cause the page to redirect to some ad-spam.

I feel like SoundCloud should first of all strip tags from track titles when they're uploaded, and also sanitize track titles (and other fields) when the API returns this object.

I don't know if the SoundCloud API devs are aware of this.  I also don't know how to make them aware.  I tried to find contact information, but couldn't.

Comment: You can submit this issue on HackerOne: https://hackerone.com/soundcloud
or fill up this form: https://scsecurity.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new

Comment: I don't think it's their responsibility to escape. I think it's yours, and exclusively yours, to escape any sort of input you get from the user or 3rd party services.

Comment: Well that seems like a philosophical question which I won't get in to.  The fact is the uploader of that track is clearly a spammer exploiting something for nefarious purposes, and the situation as is enables that.  It could also be fixed by not allowing script tags when the user first uploads the track, well before the API enters in to it.

Comment: Yes, but that sort of approach is what gives grief to every person named O'Donnell out there, just because their names have a quote in it. If my track name has a < in it (example, `<3`), there's no reason to disallow it.

Comment: I'm not talking about one character, I'm talking about a block of code.  This isn't hard to fix, and it seems like a pretty uncontroversial idea that you want to disallow user input of blocks of code like `<script>/* some javascript*/</script>`